# Categorize a number

Tags: python

Real world application: categorize bytes into the categories: control, printable, non-printable character (category list will be longer)

I have a list of numbers:

```
numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

Now I want to put them into different categories. To do so, I have to define in which category a number belongs. So far I have two approaches, both using a predefined index/value pair.

```
category_list = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "melon", "melon", "melon"]
category_dict = {1 : "apple", 2 : "apple", 3 : "banana", 4 : "melon", 5 : "melon", 6 : "melon"}
for number in numbers:
    print category_list[number]
    category_dict[number]
```

Another option would be a list for every category. This is eventually faster to write/implement but forces me to brute-force the dictionary (see one of the answers):

```
dict_category = {
    apple : [1, 2],
    banana : [3,],
    melon : [4, 5, 6]
}
for number in numbers:
    for key, val in dict_category.iteritems():
        if number in val:
            print key
            break
```

Is there a better, more pythonic way to do this? Maybe which doesn't require me to write a list/dict with 256 entries?

Comment: I don't see the connection between the `numbers` variable and the categories. Where do numbers that are higher than 6 fit into?

Comment: WHat do you need to be able to DO with this data?

Comment: As a Python interpreter, I'd throw a lot of `IndexError`s and `KeyError`s on that code.

Comment: @Juhana, This is a lazy example. Scott Hunter, I have a list of unknown numbers and I want to put them into a category.

Comment: Could you show an actual example along with the expected output, please?

Comment: @Juhana, do you want me to change the range of the numbers in numbers to 1 to 6? Do you really need this to understand the question?

Comment: I assume you want `[1,2,3]` to print `apple, apple, banana`, but the question is vague enough that I'm not really sure.

Comment: Do you really expect us to put **our non-lazy efforts** to solve **your lazy example**?

Comment: @Juhana, that's how you can read it. Basically I want to know the category X for the number Y.

Comment: @RikPoggi I hope my edit makes it more readable now...

Comment: What is an unknown number? The question is still not clear.

Comment: @Glaslos: It's still not clear. What are your starting data? `numbers` and `category_dict`? What's the meaning of `category_list`? How `category_dict` is built? *(Don't answer with a comment, update your question)*

Comment: @jimifiki I only know the range of the numbers in my list. Unknown is a bad choice in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# configuration dict, written by the user
categories = {
    'apple'  : [1, 2],
    'banana' : [3],
    'melon'  : [4, 5, 6]
}

# dynamically generate lookup table
lookup = {}
for cat, nums in categories.iteritems():
    for n in nums: lookup[n] = cat

# ... later:
from collections import defaultdict
categorized = defaultdict(list)
for n in numbers:
    cat = lookup.get(n)
    if not cat:
        continue
    categorized[cat].append(n)
    print "put %d in category %s" % (n, cat)
```

If your numbers are within a certain range, you could also use a vector for lookup:

```
lookup = [None]*256
for cat, nums in categories.iteritems():
    for n in nums: lookup[n] = cat

# ... later
categorized = defaultdict(list)
for n in numbers:
    categorized[lookup[n]].append(n)
    print "put %d in category %s" % (n, lookup[n])
```

Comment: I like the lookup table approach, this prevents me from doing the brute-forcing but keeps the faster and more readable implementation using a dictionary with lists as values.

Comment: @Glaslos: I added a suggestion for a static lookup table using an array, you can use that if you only have numbers within a certain range (in which case it should be faster).

Comment: (+1) Even though there's no need for a lambda, you can just use `list`.

Comment: @Glaslos: If this helped you, you are invited to upvote and accept this answer (using the up arrow and tick on the left side)

Comment: @NiklasB. No worries, you already got the upvote. I wait a couple of hours and if nothing else comes up, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to lookup values from `dict`s by index than it is to iterate over them and do a brute-force search for your key.  I'm not sure if that answers your question completely, but it seems to be at least part of it.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely true. How would you generate such a dictionary if you have to cover a large number of categories (lets say 20) and a large number of numbers (let's say more than 200)

Comment: Those aren't really large numbers in the context of `dict`s.  Without knowing anything else about your problem or where the data is coming from, I would put the data in a data file, or hard code it into a `dict` literal.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a way around having/writing a dict with 200 entries.

Comment: There might be, but there is no way to know for sure unless you tell us where the data is coming from.

Comment: I don't see the difference, but okay. I read bytes and I want to categorize them as control character, printable, non-printable and so on...

Comment: Yes, it does matter.  For categorization of character types, you can use the string module constants, which you can find at http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants to build your dict.

Comment: It would if I din't need more categories. I have to split up the string constants into smaller groups, but thanks for the tip.